# Is it possible to make this function more readable?

Tags: rust

I have [this function](https://github.com/frederikhors/axum-upload-local-and-cloud/blob/main/src/main.rs#L98-L136):

```rust
fn init_clients() -> (upload_executor::Executor, download_executor::Executor) {
    let client_fs = if USE_CLOUD {
        None
    } else {
        Some(Arc::new(adapter_fs::Client::new(".")))
    };

    let client_cloud = if USE_CLOUD {
        Some(Arc::new(
            adapter_s3::Client::new(
                "https://s3.region.aws.com",
                "region",
                "bucket_name",
                "KEY_ID",
                "KEY_SECRET",
            )
            .unwrap(),
        ))
    } else {
        None
    };

    let client = match USE_CLOUD {
        true => client_cloud
            .as_ref()
            .map(|o| o.clone() as Arc<dyn AdapterTrait>)
            .unwrap(),
        false => client_fs
            .as_ref()
            .map(|o| o.clone() as Arc<dyn AdapterTrait>)
            .unwrap(),
    };

    let upload_executor = upload_executor::Executor::new(client.clone());

    let download_executor = download_executor::Executor::new(client);

    (upload_executor, download_executor)
}
```

I would like to know how to make it more readable, like:

```rust
let upload_client: TraitA + TraitB = if USE_CLOUD {
    upload_client = fs::new()
} else {
    upload_client = s3::new()
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you need the inner `upload_client =` part?

Comment: The fact that `USE_CLOUD` shows up all over the place here is a sign you have a different problem, that being you probably should have two different things that implement `init_clients()` and you should select which one to use based on that setting. Maybe they both implement some trait that defines `init_clients()` so you can abstract out the mess here.

Comment: I do not understand...

Comment: Why do you split the code into effectively 3 if expressions when it should be only one? You don't use `client_fs` in the `cloud` path and don't use `client_cloud` in the `fs` path so why do you try to merge them so hard just to unwrap the appropriate one later

Comment: @cafce25 I do not understand... can you write an example?

Comment: The answer was wrong sorry. The adapters are many more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merged the sections together you could create something like this. Also keep in mind that I haven't checked this in an IDE so I am not completely sure if I correctly converted to an anonymous trait.

```
fn init_s3_client() -> Arc<adapter_s3::Client> {
    let client = adapter_s3::Client::new(
        "https://s3.region.aws.com",
        "region",
        "bucket_name",
        "KEY_ID",
        "KEY_SECRET");

    match client {
        Ok(x) => Arc::new(x),
        Err(err) => panic!("Failed to create s3 client: {:?}", err),
    }
}

fn init_clients() -> (upload_executor::Executor, download_executor::Executor) {
    let client = match USE_CLOUD {
        true => init_s3_client() as Arc<dyn AdapterTrait>,
        false => Arc::new(adapter_fs::Client::new(".")) as Arc<dyn AdapterTrait>,
    };

    let upload_executor = upload_executor::Executor::new(client.clone());
    let download_executor = download_executor::Executor::new(client);

    (upload_executor, download_executor)
}
```

Comment: So, are you telling me that `as Arc<dyn AdapterTrait>` fixes it?

Comment: @FredHors It will, assuming I wrote that conversion correctly. By converting them to a boxed anonymous trait we are giving them the same type `Arc<dyn AdapterTrait>`. This is why `client` is a valid variable in your original code despite needing to separate them previously.

Comment: The answer was wrong sorry. The adapters are many more.